# TYPO3 - how to have backend user as model property?

Tags: model, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I've defined a model in my TYPO3 extension where I want one property referring to the backend user who has performed some certain action on it in the backend module. Unfortunately I'm not quite sure how to implement it, since on one side there doesn't seem to be a backend user model class which I can refer to, on the other side defining the TCA referring to the `be_users` table like this

```
'respondentUser' => [
    'label' => 'Respondent',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'be_users',
        'maxitems' => 1
    ]
],
```

only returns objects with an empty user value (with the user UID set by myself). The at first glance more obvious `user` type didn't turn out to be what I needed either. Is there any support for model-user-relationships at all?

If not, I could work with the user's UID as integer alone. I know that I can get it through `$GLOBALS['BE_USERS']->user['uid']`, but how would I receive the user data (the username, to be accurate) from an UID?

Answer (score 1):

Check your TCA https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html - for `type:select` a `renderType` is mandatory.

Regarding your wish for a BackendUser model: there is `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser` (and its `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository`). So you can just get away with defining your model property `respondentUser` as `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser` and your Extbase repository will do the data-knitting.

For the domain modeling evangelists you should reimplement it in your domain and check out the table <> Extbase class mapping here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/5-modeling-the-class-hierarchy.html. 
If you go that road, check out https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-typoscript-setup-typoscript and mind that `ext_typoscript_setup` has deficits. I would use `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptSetup()`.

That said, there is absolutely no obligation to use Extbase in TYPO3. You can fetch the be_user record from your be_user.uid with https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html to get a raw record. Most often that is just enough to work with it.

Comment: Ah well, I should've found out myself that there's a native domain for backend users after all... looks good for me now, except that instead of the user's UID a `NULL` will be saved. I added `'renderType' => 'selectSingle'` to the TCA, anything else that's missing?

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?